# How would I implement these equations in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to implement a paper. In it I need to calculate the centre of gravity and second order moment of an image.

The equations of centre of gravity and second order moment are respectively given as:

[image]

Im having trouble trying to code this in Matlab ss from what I understand `p(x,y)` is the pixel of the image, but I'm having trouble what `y` represents and how would I implement in in the `sum` function. This is my implementation of the first equation but since I did not incorporate the `y` in there I'm sure the result given is wrong.

```
img = imread(path);
m = numel(img);
cog = sum(img(:))/m;
```

Answer (score 1):

i think, `m` should be the maximum of `y`, because `f2` is a function of `x` which means in Matlab it should be a vector.

try this code to implement f2:

```
img = magic(10)
m = 10;
temp = 0;
for y = 1:m
    temp = temp+y*img(:,y);
   %temp = temp+y*img(y,:);  % depends on your image coordinates system
end
f2 = temp/m
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. But ``f2`` does not give me  a single value as expected but gives me a vector

Comment: can you provide more details about your image processing problem which seemingly does not match these equations you gave.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code that uses vectorized anonymous functions.

```
% Read the image into an array (3 dimensions).
% Note: you may need to convert to doubles
img = im2double(imread(path));

% Get the size (may need to switch m and n).
[m, n, o] = size(img);

% Create y vector
y = 1:m;

% Create functions (not sure how you want to handle the RGB values).
f2 = @(x, p) sum(y.*p(x,:,1)/m);
f3 = @(x, p) sum(y.^2.*p(x,:,1)/(m^2));

% Call the functions
x = 10; % Some pixel x position
f2_result = f2(x, img);
f3_result = f3(x, img);
```

Note: I may have the x and y switched depending on the orientation of your image. If that's the case then switch things around like this:

```
[n, m, o] = size(img);
...
f2 = @(x, p) sum(y.*p(:,x)/m);
etc...
```

I'm not at work so I can't run the `im2double` function (don't have the library) but I think it will work.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution. I had to look into anonymous functions to understand your post. But its still not clear. What is the purpose of ``x`` here? If it is a single pixel position, will I have to use a for loop for the full image? Also your solution does not work, and gives error of ``matrix dimensions must agree`` even after switching the variables. P.S. My images are grayscale/logical so there is no RGB or 3rd dimension